# React Native: error of undefine is not object(evaluating '_react2.PropsTypes.string')

Tags: react-native

I am starting a project in react native with expo and works well in starting.Then I install react native-matreial-design in my project and import for Example Button from react-native-material-design, I get the following error.[image: error]

My Code looks like this

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { View } from 'react-native';
 import { Button } from 'react-native-material-design';

 export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
         <View>
           <Button value="NORMAL FLAT" onPress={()=> console.log("I pressed a flat button")} />
           <Button value="NORMAL RAISED" raised={true} onPress={()=> console.log("I pressed a raised button")} />
          </View>
      );
   }
 }
```

Comment: It claims that error is on *Icon.js* file. That code looks like it has something to do with *App.js*, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed it. MY problem was Proptypes define in react-native-material-design.
so i changed changed : Node_modules-> react-native-material-design->lib
and replace proptypes define

```
import Proptypes from 'react';
```

to

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

in all file inside of lib folder
Button.js,Checkbox.js, IconToggle.js, Progress.js, RadioButton.js, RangeSlider.js, Ripple.js, Slider.js, Textfield.js, and all others files.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your version of React Native and `react-native-material-design`.  The use of `PropTypes` has changed in the last few months to [a separate library](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types).  React Native gave warnings for quite a while noting that `React.PropTypes` would be deprecated and it looks like they finally did in [version 0.47.2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.47.2).

So, `react-native-material-design` is still using `React.PropTypes`.  Here is the issue in `Icon.js`:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

...

static propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  style: View.propTypes.style,
  size: PropTypes.number,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  allowFontScaling: PropTypes.bool
};
```

You'll either need to downgrade RN, fix this for them in a fork and put in a PR, or use another library.  There's already [an issue](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design/issues/170).